# Mostrar resultados de un script en .txt , PowerShell

Tags: powershell

He creado el siguiente script para ver el ultimo inicio de sesión de sesión de cada usuario.

```
Get-ADUser-filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | Format-Table LastLogonDate, Name 

Select-String "Documentos" logon.txt | out-file resultado.txt 

Clear-Host 

Get-Content resultado.txt
```

El problema es que el fichero lo crea pero sin mostrar el resultado.

Answer (score 3):

El resultado del Get-ADUser-filter no lo estas guardando en ninguna variable o archivo

```
Get-ADUser-filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | Format-Table LastLogonDate, Name
```

Es posible que lo que estes intentando hacer sea lo siguiente:

```
Get-ADUser-filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | Format-Table LastLogonDate, Name | out-file logon.txt

Select-String "Documentos" logon.txt | out-file resultado.txt

Clear-Host

Get-Content resultado.txt
```